# How does the login check_path route work without default controller/action?

Tags: symfony, yaml, symfony-2.3, symfony-routing

I am working on symfony 2.3 project having the following routing code

```
just2_frontend_logincheck:
    pattern:   /login_check
```

It doesn't have

```
defaults:{ _controller: testBundle:User:login }
```

But it is working. But I don't know how the routing is working. Is it possible? Please advice me about the routing.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The **[check_path](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)** route/path is used by your firewall to catch login requests.

This route's action is never really accessed. It's the route/url your login form posts to and the request should be processed by your firewall's provider service.

If the `check_path` route's action is being executed there is something wrong with the firewall (the request is not processed by your firewall).

As you can see [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L68) FOSUserBundle"s check_path is routed to `SecurityController::checkAction` and just throws a `RuntimeException`.

The configuration of the check_path can be found in `app/config/security.yml` under  `security.firewalls.<firewallname>.form_login.check_path`.

It can either be a pattern like `/login_check` or as in your case a route name i.e. `just2_frontend_logincheck` but there is no underlying action.

```
security:
    providers:
         your_provider_name: your_provider_service  # authentication provider
         # ...

    firewalls:                                 # Required
        your_firewall_name:
            # ...

            provider: your_provider_name
            form_login:              
                check_path: /login_check       # submit the login form here
                                               # in your case a route name:
                                               # just2_frontend_logincheck
```

Under the hood symfony calls the `authenticate()` method of the service `your_provider_service` to check the credentials provided.

You can find the class used as the provider-service using:

```
app/console debug:container --show-private your_provider_service
```

Comment: Where to start debugging if the route is *not* processed by the firewall?

Comment: @hchr - start testing wether the `check_path`'s route exists by debugging the router somewhat like this:  `app/console debug:router | grep -i <route_name_or_path>` . Then comment out/disable all except one firewall under `security.firewalls` and slim down that single firewall's configuration to a **minimum**. My answer shows a minimal example that should be enough to catch the request at `/login_check`