# symfony 3 route not found for login/ register

Tags: symfony, routes

I dont use FOS
What is wrong? My links directs to "login" and "register" and I am getting this:

```
No route found for "GET /login/"
```

Also getting this for register

```
No route found for "GET /register/"
```

My debug:router looks like:

[image]

Entity and Controller are in UserBundle routing.yml:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751181/fosuserbundle-no-route-found-for-get-login

Comment: Do any routes work? Like /article or even /?

Comment: Yes everything works just /register and /login not

Answer (score 0):

Because You did pass this:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

If you use `2 > version` `FOSUserBundle`

```
# app/config/routing.yml
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

I would recommend you to read this documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i recently edited my question. I dont use FOS

Comment: No i stil do not know, i dont use FOS bundle

Comment: You have to install `FOSUserBundle`, without this bundle it doesn't work. That is why I would recommend you to review  the following: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev Does this answer wrote for another question? Why he should use FOS if he don't want? EasyAdminBundle works pretty well without FOS and I don't see nothing have a strict dependance from FOS o-O.

Comment: @gp_sflover, If the one wants use it `SonataBundle` feel free to do so. I think `SonataBundle` is bundle works very pretty and have many functions. I suggest use this bundle then `EasyAdminBundle`.

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev The point being is that all your FOSUserBundle stuff is completely irrelevant to this question.  Almost like you just guessed.

Comment: I hope that i do not need to install FOSUserBudle, everything until my previous error was working. When I fixed that problem this problem appears. But still do not understand what is wrong with my code