# Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check" in symfony 2

Tags: security, symfony

I'm new to Symfony2 and I'm trying to create a basic login system.
This is my security.yml page:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false


    secured_area:
        pattern:  /^
        form_login: 
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
```

I am getting the login page but when I submit the form i get a exception that

"Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?"

Comment: do you have a route named `login_check` defined? Please read [**my answer here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406446/how-does-the-login-check-path-route-work-without-default-controller-action/17406584#17406584) to understand how the `check_path` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions closely on the symfony docs for [Using a Login Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form).  If you follow these instructions, you shouldn't have any issues with your login_check.