# Functional test for a simple login form with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, testing

I've been trying to write simple login test and this is my action ( the data should log me in ):

```
 $client = self::createClient();

 $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');

 $form = $crawler->selectButton('Submit')->form();

 $form['_username'] = 'admin';
 $form['_password'] = 'adminpass';

 $client->submit($form);
 //$crawler = $client->followRedirect();

 $this->assertEquals('Portal\FrontendBundle\Controller\ProfileController::indexAction', $client->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller'));
```

And it stops on checkAction:

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'Portal\FrontendBundle\Controller\ProfileController::indexAction'
+'FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController::checkAction'
C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\src\Portal\FrontendBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest.php:24
```

If I'm following redirect than it comes back to loginAction.

I'm new to Unit tests actually and I don't really know how I'm supposed to write it properly.

Comment: You're acutally writing a *functional* test and not a unit test there :)

Comment: oops, well I guess it's easy to notice that I'm not familiar with tests :) do You know maybe what am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your login-form working regularly? if **[`SecurityController::checkAction`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L70)** is invoked - you usually have a misconfigured firewall. That action only throws the exception **You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration** .

Comment: btw. you can have a look at **[my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17406584/1832745)** for an explanation of the `check_path` configuration. That will probably guide you into the right direction.

Comment: it is configured, also - I can log in via the website, so I think something is wrong with the test? Or with my understanding how it works.

Comment: The test is usually executed in the `test` environment. Check your configuration - mainly that `config_test.yml` actually exists and imports `config.yml` which in turn imports `security.yml`. This means a working form in the prod/dev environment doesn't necessarily mean your test environment has the same configuration.

Comment: it does exist and also import config_dev. Btw my check path has value "fos_user_security_check" - I don't know if that changes anything?

Comment: did you maybe import FOSUserbundle's routing in `routing_dev.yml` instead of `routing.yml` ? try `app/console router:debug --env=test`

Comment: nope.. it is in routing.yml. Also Your command shows it is there.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you are testing it in the correct environment?
is your user "admin" stored in the database? you should follow the
redirect I think ... maybe the login just fails because of bad credentials...
try to validate it with:

```
$this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("bad credentials")')->count() > 0);
```

or something similar...