# Understanding Symfony/FOSUserBundle Authentication - How is fos_user_security_check handled

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I am trying to understand the how authentication (user + password) is handled in `Symfony 2.8` when using the `FOSUserBundle`. The setup was no problem and everything works fine, I just want to understand HOW it work.

The login form post username + password to the `fos_user_security_check` route (`/login_check`) which is defined in `FOSUserBunde\Resources\config\routing\security.xml`:

```
<route id="fos_user_security_check" path="/login_check" methods="POST">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:check</default>
</route>
```

So the `FOSUserBundle:Security:check` action is responsible for handling the request. However the implementation looks like this:

```
public function checkAction() {
    throw new \RuntimeException('You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.');
}
```

So I looked at the firewall config in `/app/config/security.yml`:

```
security:
    ...
    firewalls:
        ...
        main:
            ...

            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
```

Here `check_path` also referes to `fos_user_security_check`... So, where is the authentication actually handeled?

Comment: Why the down vote? If there is something wrong with the question, please leave a comment and let me know what I can do better. I down vote without any hint about what is wrong is not very help full. Thank!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The authentication isn't handled inside the FOSUserBundle, it is just providing some basic parameters as well as a provider for how to retrieve the user from the database (`fos_userbundle`).

You'll want to look at `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AbstractAuthenticationListener` for some basics about what happens on authentication failure and success.  You can look at `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener` and the `attemptAuthentication()` method there, and follow along there to the authentication manager service that calls `authenticate()`.

You will eventually get to `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder` and the `isPasswordValid()` function, which checks whatever encoder you have (probably `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder`) which eventually calls PHP's [password_verify](http://php.net/password_verify) function.

The reason why you see that Controller action in the way that you do, is that you should never be calling `login_check` directly.  Hence, if you got there, something has been mis-configured, which is why the exception is thrown.  See the [check_path](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#check-path) variable in the documentation, and [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17406584/1307183) for more information about that.